# How to get 'key' and 'value' column data in HashMap using Sping JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, jdbctemplate

Suppose, I have a table like below -

```
Id | Key | Value
----------------
01 | one | 1_val
02 | two | 2_val
```

I want the the two columns - Key and Value - as `HashMap`

What is the most suitable way to do that using Spring JDBC Template?

Answer (score 1):

You need something along the lines:

```
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        ResultSetExtractor<HashMap<String, String>> rse = rs -> {
            HashMap<String, String>  retVal = new HashMap<>();
            while(rs.next()) {
                retVal.put(rs.getString("Key"), rs.getString("Value"));
            }
            return retVal;
        };
        HashMap<String, String> result = template.query("select Key, Value from Table", rse);
```

Why do you want to have this as `HashMap`?

Answer (score -1):

You could have a method to create that object for you

```
public Map<String, String> getTableAsMap() throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT Key, Value FROM KeyValueTable;");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    while (rs.next())
    {
        map.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
    }

    return map;
}
```

EDIT: This is not Spring but you should get the idea.